# How do I simplify and generalize this subset command in R?

Tags: r, subset

In an analysis script I have to do the following subset command a lot of times:

```
subset(df1, A == df2[1,'A'] & V == df2[1,'B'] & C == df2[1,'C'] & D == df2[1,'D'])
```

**Is there a way in R to generalize this command?** I would like to have something like

```
classifiers <- c(
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D'
  )

subset(df1, classifiers == df2[1,classifiers])
```

Comment: Do you want to know all the rows of df1 which have columns values A, B, C, D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2[1, classifiers])
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's even better!

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
#Some data:
set.seed(42)
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:4],400,TRUE),ncol=4))
#e.g., classifiers <- DF2[1, c('A','B')]
classifiers <- c(
  'A',
  'B'
) 

ind <- colSums(t(DF[,c('V1','V2')])==classifiers)==length(classifiers)

DF[ind,]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#18  A  B  B  C
#22  A  B  A  B
#43  A  B  A  D
#72  A  B  D  B
#73  A  B  B  D
#75  A  B  D  C
```

Answer (score 1):

A verbose approach is to construct the subset criterion as a string dynamically and evaluate it afterwards, e.g.

**Preparing some data**

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(replicate(4, sample(1:3, 10, rep=T)))
names(df1) <- LETTERS[1:4]
df2 <- df1
```

**Your approach**

```
subset(df1, A == df2[1,'A'] & B == df2[1,'B'] & C == df2[1,'C'] & D == df2[1,'D'])

  A B C D
1 2 1 1 2
```

**Constructing the subset criterion**

```
classifiers <- LETTERS[1:4]
subs <- paste0(classifiers, "== df2[1,'", classifiers, "']", collapse=" & ")
subset(df1, eval(parse(text=subs)))

  A B C D
1 2 1 1 2
```

`paste` creates the criterion as a string, i.e. `"A== df2[1,'A'] & B== df2[1,'B'] & C== df2[1,'C'] & D== df2[1,'D']"`. The eval-parse combination evaluates the string as an expression.

Comment: Fortune 106: "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question. —Thomas Lumley"